# How to safely terminate objects running on different threads in QT

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I am learning how to run objects on different threads. I started with this simple exercise to run objects on different threads and communicate between them. Now, I have trouble terminating the program. How to safely destroy the objects running in different threads when main exits? If I put a wait on threads before main for the completion of threads, the program hangs at wait(). If I don't put a wait, threads are never executed and threads are deleted immediately as main exits.

```
    --------testthread.h------------------
    #ifndef TESTTHREAD_H
    #define TESTTHREAD_H

   #include <QThread>
   #include <QApplication>
   #include <string>
   #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;
   class testThread : public QObject
   {
     Q_OBJECT
     public:
     testThread(const string&, QThread*);
    ~testThread();
private:
    QThread* thread;
    string _threadName;
signals:
    void requestCalculateSquare(int);
public slots:
    void calculateSquare(int);
    void start();

  };

   #endif // TESTTHREAD_H}

   -----testthread.cpp---------------------
   #include "testthread.h"
   #include <iostream>
   //#include "moc_testthread.cpp"

   testThread::~testThread()
   {}

   testThread::testThread(const string& threadName, QThread* thread):QObject()
   {
      _threadName = threadName;
       moveToThread(thread);
       connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()),this,SLOT(start()));
   }

   void testThread::calculateSquare(int i)
   {
      cout<<_threadName<<" "<<i*i;
   }

   void testThread::start()
    {
       for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
       {
         emit requestCalculateSquare(i);
       }
         emit finished();
    }

     --------main.cpp--------------------------
    #include <iostream>
    #include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
    #include <string> 
    #include "testthread.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
       QApplication app(argc,argv);
       string name1("Thread1");
       string name2("Thread2");
       QThread* thread1 = new QThread;
       QThread* thread2 = new QThread;
       testThread*  test1 = new testThread(name1, thread1);
       testThread* test2 = new testThread(name2, thread2);

         QObject::connect(test1,SIGNAL(requestCalculateSquare(int)),test2,SLOT(calculateSquare(int)));
QObject::connect(test2,SIGNAL(requestCalculateSquare(int)),test1,SLOT(calculateSquare(int)));
    QObject::connect(test1,SIGNAL(finished()),test2, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    QObject::connect(test1,SIGNAL(finished()),thread2, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(test2,SIGNAL(finished()),test1, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    QObject::connect(test2,SIGNAL(finished()),thread1, SLOT(quit()));

thread1->start();
thread2->start();

thread1->wait();
thread2->wait();

cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
return 0;
//return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing some funky things.

1) Each `QThread` is having `start()` called twice - first in the `testThread` constructor, then again in `main()`.  The second call won't do anything, since is is already running.

2) When you start the `QThread` in the `testThread` constructor, your loop will execute and emit the signals before they are connected - it makes me think you don't actually want to start the thread in the constructor, and instead leave it unstarted until later in `main()`.

3) `QThread::quit()` will cause the thread's event loop to return - this is what you're missing.  `connect` a "done" type signal from `testThread` to the `quit` slot, and then `QThread::wait()` will behave as you expect, with the calls returning once the loops are completed.

4) I know it's just a little test program, but you're leaking memory since you aren't calling `delete` on your `new` objects.  You actually don't need to use `new` at all here, everything can be allocated on the stack - generally a better idea.

Comment: You are right about point 1,2 and 4. I note that. But about 3, I want my object to live for long time and connect with different objects. The solution you are referring to is okay when an object calls one function and then sends some signal to terminate it. In this case, I want to communicate between the objects. I don't understand when I should emit a signal like "finished".

Comment: @shivchawla The `QThread::quit()` function is a `slot`, you can connect signals or call it directly.  Since you're using Qt, you probably want to start the main application event loop: `app.exec()` - you can interact with a `QDialog` or `QMainWindow` user interface. You can connect an "Exit" button to the `quit` slots of your threads, then `wait` for them to finish before continuing cleanup.

Comment: I just modified my main and emitted a finished signal but it still hangs at wait(). I at a very nascent stage of using all this.

Comment: @shivchawla Are you defining a `finished` signal for testThread? I don't see it in the class definition. Also, you're signaling each thread to `quit` from the other; if one thread `quits` before it signals the other to do the same, you'll never return from `wait` - this looks dangerous.

Comment: I resolved the isue. You pointed it out corrrectly. The code that I posted is dangerous. I removed         `QObject::connect(test1,SIGNAL(finished()),thread2, SLOT(quit()));`

`QObject::connect(test2,SIGNAL(finished()),thread1, SLOT(quit()));`
and added quit() in object's destructor and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do a wait on the threa\ds to prevent the main thread exiting.  Wait on STDIN or some other input, perhaps?

wait/join to threads should only be done if absolutely required, (eg. a file has to be flushed/closed, a transaction has to be committed, a DB connection has to be closed).  If you routinely join/wait on all threads just because it seems like a good idea, you will end up writing a whole load of complex code just to get threads to exit - something that is usually unnecessary.